# Persisting embedded (related) items in spring boot jpa repositories?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have the following "parent class" :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_table")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long parentId;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Child> children;
 }
```

I also have the following child class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long childId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    private String name;
}
```

I am sending up the following request in postman :

```
{
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "Parent",
        "children":[{
                "name":"jack"
            },
            {
                "name":"jill"
            }
        ]

}
```

When I ask the parent repository to save the parent, it does, but nothing happens for the child... it doesn't save to the database at all...

For reference, this is my line that saves the parent

```
parentRepository.save(parent)
```

(the parent in this case, has the two children inside of it - but they don't get saved to the children table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your example and it seems to be working correctly, only thing i change was `mappedBy` property of `@OneToMany` annotation. It must be lower case.

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_table")
public class Parent {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "parent_id")
  private Long parentId;

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
public class Child {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long childId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
  private Parent parent;

  private String name;

}
```

**Test**

Above code makes next unit case to succeed:

```
  @Test
  public void parentRepositoryMustPersistParentAndChildren() {
    Parent parent = new Parent("Anakin", "Skywalker");
    parent.getChildren().add(new Child("Luke"));
    parent.getChildren().add(new Child("Leia"));

    Parent saved = parentRepository.save(parent);

    Assert.assertNull("Parent does not have and id assigned after persist it", saved.getParentId());
    saved.getChildren().forEach((child) ->{
      Assert.assertNull("Parent does not have and id assigned after persist it", child.getChildId());
    });

  }
```

Comment: That fixed it... Thanks! - Now I just need to be able to get the parent FROM the database, and get all the children! haha!

Comment: Notice i added `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to the `OneToMany` annotation, that would make parent to load children when you call `parentRepository.findById(1L);`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, mine also has that now, but it just returns an empty array for that section in the REST response body (the parent is otherwise good) - It also doesn't help when I change to lazy.